# Who recognizes this character corruption?

Tags: php, encoding, zip

I have the following code:

```
$files = ftp_nlist($conn_id, "/path/to/files");
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open('filename.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE);
if ($res === TRUE) {
    foreach ($files as $item) {
        if ($item != '.' && $item != '..') {
            // Get file contents
            ob_start();
            @ftp_get($conn_id, "php://output", "/path/to/files/{$item}", FTP_BINARY);
            $data = ob_get_contents();
            ob_end_clean();
            $zip->addFromString($item, $data);
        }
    }
// ...
}
```

Unfortunately the file names in the zip file get corrupted. For example, ßäÄçö.txt becomes +ƒ+ñ+ä+º+¦.txt.

I am assuming this can be solved by using `iconv`, but I can't find any encoding pair that yields the desired result. As far as I know the file name is stored as UTF-8. When I don't zip the file but just download it using

```
// ...
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename*=UTF-8''".rawurlencode($item));
//...
echo $data;
```

there is no character corruption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer in the User Contributed Notes [here](http://php.net/manual/bg/function.ziparchive-addfromstring.php):

The Zip spec seems to specify IBM437 as valid encoding.

```
$encodedFilename = iconv('utf-8', 'IBM437', $filename);
$zip->addFromString($encodedFilename, 'foo');
```

solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

"ßäÄçö" in UTF-8 is encoded as `C3 9F C3 A4 C3 84 C3 A7 C3 B6`. If you read these bytes as [CP-437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437), you get "├ƒ├ñ├ä├º├╢". If you change all the "├"s (`C3`) to "+" (`2B`) and change the last character to "¦", you get "+ƒ+ñ+ä+º+¦".

I don't know why "├" becomes "+", nor why "╢" becomes "¦". I tried saving a text file named "├ƒ├ñ├ä├º├╢.txt" in Vim, and it instead created a file named "+ƒ+ñ+ä+º+¦.txt". But when I tried the same thing in Notepad, it created the correct filename "├ƒ├ñ├ä├º├╢.txt". So whatever is happening to the bytes in your Zip file is the same thing that Vim does.

The [Zip File Format Specification](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT), in Appendix D, says that file names must be in CP-437 or UTF-8, so it seems like somewhere your filename is being treated as CP-437, plus whatever additional step is munging bytes `C3` and `B6`. Perhaps there is a workaround for PHP's ZipArchive, or a different Zip library you could use. A quick search for "php ziparchive utf-8" found a lot of results, but I did not immediately see a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried `iconv("UTF-8", "CP-437", $item)` but that way  the zip shows no files at all. I'll see if there is a different Zip library as you suggested.